# ant.xslt/Xalan fails referencing namespaced nodes from an external file

Tags: xpath, xslt, ant

In an .xsl file I want to use nodes from a separate file ("foo.xsd"). The .xsl file uses an explicit namespace prefix, the external file doesn't but rather relies on a default namespace. Their namespace URIs match up.

Reading in the nodes, with `ant.xslt` the following XPath expression results in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception later

```xpath
document('foo.xsd')/xsd:schema/xsd:*
```

while it works when removing the last reference to the namespace prefix

```xpath
document('foo.xsd')/xsd:schema/*
```

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The transformation input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="bar"/>
</schema>
```

and a transformation *.xsl* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="nodeSet" select="document('foo.xsd')/xsd:schema/xsd:*[@name]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/xsd:schema/xsd:element">
      <xsl:value-of select="$nodeSet/@name"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The referenced `foo.xsd` is just a copy of the input file, so in this cut down example I'm running over one instance of the file and reading in the other instance in the stylesheet.

Goold ol' `xsltproc` is extracting the right attribute value ("bar"). `ant.xslt` with the default processor (Xalan) throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (I presume when looking for the colon insided the element name).The problem only arises when referencing `nodeSet` as in the `<xsl:value-of>` element.

The `<xsl:template>` matches in all cases, using prefixes.

**My question is:** Did I hit a bug in Xalan, or am I doing something generally wrong?

I'm aware of the various work-arounds concerning namespace prefixes, like using `[local-name() = 'element']` and such, so please don't post answers in that vein. I'm looking for a general answer whether this should work (like, according to the specs).

**Background Material**

Stacktrace (part.) that hints at Xalan:

```
...
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 512
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:783)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:370)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:201)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:870)
        ... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 512
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.SuballocatedIntVector.elementAt(SuballocatedIntVector.java:441)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase._firstch(DTMDefaultBase.java:523)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.SAXImpl.access$200(SAXImpl.java:73)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.SAXImpl$NamespaceChildrenIterator.next(SAXImpl.java:1431)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.CurrentNodeListIterator.setStartNode(CurrentNodeListIterator.java:158)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.StepIterator.setStartNode(StepIterator.java:97)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.StepIterator.setStartNode(StepIterator.java:97)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.DupFilterIterator.setStartNode(DupFilterIterator.java:97)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.CachedNodeListIterator.setStartNode(CachedNodeListIterator.java:57)
        at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.test.topLevel()
        at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.test.transform()
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(AbstractTranslet.java:624)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:776)
        ... 129 more
```

Invokation is through Gradle via shell command `gradlew mytask` using the Gradle built-in Ant using its built-in `ant.xslt` task.

*build.gradle*:

```groovy
tasks.register('mytask') {
    doLast {
        ant.xslt(
            baseDir: '.',
            in: 'input.xsd',
            out: 'out.xml',
            style: 'stylefile.xsl'
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say an IndexOfOutBoundsException is kind of a bug. I can't reproduce the problem with the Xalan version included in the current version of oXygen XML editor, however.

Comment: Testing your code with Xalan 2.7.2 using command line produced the expected result - so the problem seems to be elsewhere. The error message also does not seem to be XSLT-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xslt/xml code is fine (works with Saxon). So it's either something in the way you're running the transformation, or it's a bug in the version of Xalan that you're using.

Xalan shouldn't be throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception anyway. It's presumably Xalan code on the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've updated the question to include stacktrace and invocation information. I could see this is Xalan version dependent, but for all of my effort I haven't figured out yet which Xalan version is used in this Gradle/Ant/java.xml/JRE/... tech stack.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further. The stack trace is pretty convincing evidence of a Xalan bug.